# Error in prediction of sentiment in Scikit LogisticRegression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, sentiment-analysis

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

train_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data['review'])

test_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(test_data['review'])
```

## Training LogisticRegressor

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

sentiment_model = LogisticRegression()

sentiment_model = sentiment_model.fit(train_matrix,train_data['sentiment'])
```

## Examin sample data

```
sample_test_data = test_data[10:13]

sample_test_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(sample_test_data['review'])

predict = sentiment_model.predict(sample_test_matrix)
```

Error:

> X has 85 features per sample; expecting 121676
>
> ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
>
> in ()

----> 1 predict = model.predict(sample_test_matrix)

> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in predict(self, X)
>
> ```
>             Predicted class label per sample.
> ```
>
> ---------->   scores = self.decision_function(X)
>
> ```
>        if len(scores.shape) == 1:
>
>          indices = (scores > 0).astype(np.int)
> ```
>
> decision_function(self, X)
>
> ```
>       if X.shape[1] != n_features:
>
>           raise ValueError("X has %d features per sample; expecting %d"
>         ------------>   % (X.shape[1], n_features))
>
>     scores = safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,
> ```
>
> ValueError: X has 85 features per sample; expecting 121676

Comment: Please include the **full** stacktrace so we can see which line is throwing the error.

Comment: Amazon Product Review ,Coursera Classification Assignment . I even did the same coding as of the helpdesk but still got this error

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem you're encountering is as a result of using the `fit_transform()` method on your test set instead of just the `transform()` method. The [CountVectorizer() fit method](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.fit) learns "a vocabulary dictionary of all tokens in the raw documents."

This means that when you are calling `fit_transform()` on the training set, it will produce a sparse matrix with number of features equal to the different word tokens it finds in the text you provide it as input. When you again call `fit_transform()` on the test set, it generates a different sparse matrix with dimensions based on the unique words in the test set, instead of using the original matrix generated on the training data.

You then fit the `LogisticRegression` object to your training data, but when you try to use `predict()` on the test data it complains that the input size is different to what you passed in when you trained it because it's got a different number of features.

**EDIT:** This is also happening when you call the following:

`test_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(test_data['review'])`

You should avoid creating different fits for the `CountVectorizer` if you plan on splitting your data into training and test sets, as the resulting dimensions of the sparse matrices will cause problems like the one you're experiencing.

**TL;DR:**

Try replacing these

```
test_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(test_data['review'])
sample_test_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(sample_test_data['review'])
```

with these

```
test_matrix = vectorizer.transform(test_data['review'])
sample_test_matrix = vectorizer.transform(sample_test_data['review'])
```

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work now its giving : ValueError: X has 49745 features per sample; expecting 121676

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention you also before that need to also change the `test_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(test_data['review'])` to use only `transform()` as well. I knew that was a problem but I overlooked it when I was writing up my response since you don't seem to actually use test_matrix anywhere. Nevertheless, by fitting the `CountVectorizer` to create `test_matrix` you're doing the same thing. Fix that one as well and it should work now.

Comment: NotFittedError: CountVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted. sorry,but still it didn't worked

Comment: Did you remove all of them? Don't remove the initial training fit, just the one for the test sets.